# Entity Framework add method - completed event

Tags: methods, frameworks, insert, entity

I have a WCF service with Entity Framework and I created a method to insert a new entry in a database (RateMovie() ), and other methods to get data (like GetMovies() )

I want to call the RateMovie() method from a Windows Phone 8 application and do other things when it's completed (update the average rating of a movie... ).

Here is my code :

```
client.RateMovieCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.RateMovieCompletedEventArgs>(client_rateMovieCompleted);
client.RateMovieAsync(idMovie, idDevice, rating);
```

But the "RateMovieCompletedEventArgs" event does not exist...

I think this is normal, because my method RateMovie() doesn't return anything....

Is there a way to know when the entry is inserted to the database ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally add a return value to the RateMovie() method to have a completedEvent